# Translating Python to C# - Random Array

Tags: c#, python-2.7

As I am learning C# I am recreating one of my old projects that I did in python which was a D&D style character randomizer. I am working on the random stat generation but I seem to be having trouble getting actual values and not a `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'    error.

Python Code:

```
def char_stats(self):
    # roll 4 D6s drop the lowest number and add the highest 3
    # this is done for each stat slot
    stats = []
    for x in range(6):
        rolls =[randint(1,6) for i in range(4)]
        rolls.sort()
        stats.append(sum(rolls[1:]))
    return stats
```

My C# Code so far:

```
List<int> rolls = new List<int>();
Random rollrnd = new Random();
IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    rolls.Add(rollrnd.Next(1,6));
    Console.WriteLine(rolls);
    //System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
   // loop to go with Enumerable
   //foreach (int n in range){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you C# code you are not getting an error. `Console.WriteLine(rolls)` is displaying the returned value of `rolls.ToString()` which is *System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]*. If you are wanting to display the individual values that are stored within `rolls` you would need to use code like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int roll = rollrnd.Next(1,6);
    rolls.Add(roll);
    Console.WriteLine(roll);
}
```

Comment: this is interesting, I thought I had tried this before and was still getting the same answer. Thank you very much.  I wonder how much more difficult this will be when I incorporate a GUI to this to allocate stats, but that is another day!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display all the elements of a sequence you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", rolls));
```

Your call to random.Next is wrong. I don't know what python does, but in C# `Next(1, 6)` gives random numbers from 1 to 5, unfortunately.

A useful helper for your problem space is an *infinite sequence of dice rolls*:

```
static Random random = new Random();
static IEnumerable<int> Dice(int n) {
  while(true)
    yield return random.Next(1, n + 1);
}
```

Now you can use sequence operators. So for example, roll four, discard the lowest, and sum the results is:

```
Dice(6).Take(4).OrderBy(x => x).Skip(1).Sum();
```

Notice how by using sequence operators you avoid doing loops and ranges entirely. Of course there are loops inside Take and Skip, but that's their business. You don't need loops polluting your code. Make your code look like the operations it is encoding: roll some dice, discard some, sum them.

Comment: This is really awesome! I am going to look at this, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use Generic List ForEach method as shown below, I've also put vars in as this is viewed as good practice:

```
        var rolls = new List<int>();
        var rollrnd = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            rolls.Add(rollrnd.Next(1, 6));
        }

        rolls.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x)); // These lines are equivalent
        rolls.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);        // Just showing another way of doing it.
    }
```

Comment: I was looking at using the foreach, I didn't know that I could actually just for a foreach like that on a list! Shows how little I know so far, but this is a great help!

Comment: Glad it was useful. Note though that you can't change the values in the list in the rolls.ForEach method, or by using the foreach(var roll in rolls)  approach, you'd have to use a for() to do that; it's all to do with immutable enumerators which is what your actually dealing with in foreach stuff. Just thought I'd point this out as it's a bit of a 'gotcha' when learning :)